# Kubernetes master high availability or replication configuration

Tags: replication, kubernetes, high-availability, failovercluster

Hi all we are looking for practically and tested guide or reference  for kubernetes master high availability or other solution for master node fail over.

Comment: Thank you all of you I have found Multimaster HA Kubernetes cluster configuration tool KOPS. https://github.com/kubernetes/kops

Answer (score 3):

There are definitely folks running Kubernetes HA masters in production following the instructions for [High Availability Kubernetes Clusters](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/admin/high-availability.md). As noted at the beginning of that page, it's an advanced use case and requires in-depth knowledge of how the Kubernetes master components work.